# This opertion gives overflow and carry?

Tags: arithmetic

Take this example in 2's complement representation with 8 bits.

1111 1110 + 1111 1110 ( -2 + -2 = -4 )
Calculation:

```
  1111 1110
 +1111 1110
 -----------
1|1111 1100 = -4 in 2's complement
```

This operation gives overflow and carry at the same time?

Comment: You need to calculate the overflow/carry flags as generated by a microprocessor ?

Comment: yes its to calculate overflow and carry flags but my question is they can both be set to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have no overflow, summing up two negative numbers giving negative number there is no overflow flag.
Carry flag is there, but since you have signed numbers, it does not matter.

But the ALU does not know whether it was signed, so flags it anyway.

It might occur at once:
-70 + -100
  10111010
+10011100
101010110

Result is carried and overflowed - it changed sign while both operands were not, and does not fit to 8bit representation.